# phonegap command line build errors

Tags: cordova

I am trying to compile the project using phonegap commandline using `phonegap build ios`, but got error saying:

> execvp(): Permission denied.

Then I changed all files in project with chmod 777, still doesn't work.

I then tried `sudo phonegap build ios`, and with following errors:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/admin/CurvelurveNative/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch'
>   clang: error: no input files
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       ProcessPCH /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.1-5B130a/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/CordovaLib_Prefix-gvmoqaqteektjvafgqfbaiggmjge/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch  CordovaLib_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c  com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>   { [Error: /Users/admin/testproject/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65] code: 65 }
>      [error] /Users/admin/testproject/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65

Comment: I see you've used `chmod 777`, but still, did you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25433980/4412363?