# Phonegap Hook - execvp Permission denied

Tags: cordova, hook

I'm trying to run a phonegap hook which I found on the net but I always get the same error on build

`execvp() Permission denied`

the hook is the "splash and icon" hook located here:

http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/#comment-332073

any help is much appreciated

Comment: on a side note, just found it has nothing to do with the script. It is to do with the folder "before_build" i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer

`chmod -R 777 before_build`

Answer (score 1):

Even i got the same error when i tried to add a platform to the ionic application. Its not just the problem with phone gap. It is also a headache while adding platforms in an ionic application. I was searching for the solution and finally, i landed at this page. Based on `Luke Snowden` answer i tried to find the solution. But in ionic app, there won't be any folder with the name `before_build`. And the solution is just changing the mode of files present in the `hooks` folder. The permissions should have `+x` i.e. execute permissions.

Go to hooks folder, you may find the following two folders

1) after_prepare
2) before_platform_add

Change the permissions of two folders to `+x`

```
chmod -x <folder name>
```

You can even change individual file's permission also.
Go to the respected folder and say

```
chmod -x <file name>
```

for each file to change the mode to `+x`.

After you are done with the above process, now we can add platforms to the application.

```
ionic platform add android
```

Now it wont show any errors on the console.

Hope this might help people who are facing the similar kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the root folder and go one folder upwards. Then give execute permission only rather than giving `777`. This worked for me.

```
chmod -R +x folder_name
```

[cordova build Command failed with exit code EACCES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409541/cordova-build-command-failed-with-exit-code-eacces)